# Java Shooting targets

Tags: java, methods

I have been working on this for almost one week. The question is mainly about shooting the target. So we ask the user to input v0, degree, x0, and y0. We will be setting two targets(500,0)&(1000,0).

I think I did all the methods correctly except for the main methos.

**The question I am having now is I have no idea about how to put the "return"s back to the main method.(For example, I got the time and I returned it, but how can I output "The time it took to get to the groud is +time+".**

It is my first time working with method questions, I would be happy to see some advice!!

**Also I've been told to give the user 4 chances to play this game and give the user to choose whether they are going to start again or exit. I saw many people useing boolean to work this part, but I have no idea about how to use it.**

The following is what I got so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class AngryBirdGame{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int vo,degree = 0,xo = 0,yo = 0;
        System.out.println("This game is the Angry Bird Game. You will be trying to hit the target.");
        System.out.println("One of the targets of the game is (500,0)");
        System.out.println("The other target of the game is (1000,0)");
        System.out.println("Please enter the initial velocity");
        vo=velocity();
        System.out.println("Please enter the angle of elevation(0-90 degrees)");
        degree=degree(degree);
        System.out.println("Please enter the horizontal starting point(50-500)");
        xo=horizontal(xo);
        System.out.println("Please enter the vertical starting point");
        yo=vertical(yo);

        result(0);
    }
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Drive-by comment: `int π` is nonsensical, because a) pi isn't an integer; b) pi isn't a variable. Just use the constant from `java.lang.Math`, or even just use `Math.toRadians`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow the user to play multiple games, you need a loop in your `main()` method. Also, as a matter of organization, it would be convenient to define a class that encapsulated all the data the user needs to provide to get a game started. (The class `AngryBirdGame` probably works just fine for that.) You can then extract all the logic for obtaining the user's input into a separate method that returns an instance of the game data class, or `null` if the user doesn't want to play any more. Similarly, you should define a method that returns the result of the game so you can report the result to the user each time through the loop.

Finally, my guess is that your input variables should be floating point numbers (or maybe even `double`) rather than `int` values. It's hard to do trajectory calculations accurately using integer values only.

Putting all that together, here's an outline of what it might look like:

```
public class AngryBirdGame {
    float vo, degree, xo, yo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printOneTimeIntro();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0, AngryBirdGame game = getGameInfo(in);
                 i < 4 && game != null;
                 i++, game = getGameInfo()) {
            float time = game.play();
            System.out.format("The time it took to get to the ground is %f%n", time);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A static method to print a one-time introduction to the program.
     */
    private static void printOneTimeIntro() {
        System.out.println("This game is the Angry Bird Game. You will be trying to hit the target.");
    }

    /**
     * A static method to check whether the user wants to play and, if so,
     * to collect all the game info.
     *
     * @return a game object, or {@code null} if the user no longer wants to play.
     */
    private static AngryBirdGame getGameInfo(Scanner in) {
        // first check if the user wants to play
        System.out.println("Do you want to play (y/n)? ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("n")) {
            return null;
        }

        // if so, create a game object and get all the input
        AngryBirdGame game = new AngryBirdGame();
        System.out.println("One of the targets of the game is (500,0)");
        System.out.println("The other target of the game is (1000,0)");
        System.out.println("Please enter the initial velocity");
        game.v0 = in.nextFloat();
        // TODO: get rest of input

        return game;
    }

    /**
     * An instance method that plays the game once everything is initialized.
     *
     * @return the time it takes for the trajectory to complete
     */
    private float play() {
        float time;

        // TODO: calculate the game time to reach the ground

        return time;
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to return more information than just the trajectory time, you might want to define a second class to contain everything you want returned and use that as the return value from `play()`.